# get the application's resources languages

Tags: android

Is it possible, at runtime, to know which resources languages are embedded in my app?

i.e the presence of this folders:

```
values-en
values-de
values-fr
...
```

Comment: Just curious: but by default wouldn't you know which locales are there since you put them in the app?

Comment: You're right! but i'm creating a library(so end developers can add languages) and i need to know programmatically how many are embedded

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AssetManager.getLocales() is actually the way to do this.  However, from the public API every AssetManager you create also has the framework resources included in its search path...  so when you call AssetManager.getLocales() you will also see any locales that are part of the framework resources.  There is no way to get around this with the SDK, sorry.

Comment: There's `AssetManager.getNonSystemLocales()` but it has my favorite `@hide` tag in the JavaDoc. It is [exactly what Android uses to determine which locale to use](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/c37457799be3db0590a5d94832b2fef5f64ef439/core/java/android/content/res/ResourcesImpl.java#402) to access the resources in your app. Also, it's "available" only since Nougat.

Comment: I started wondering how it was done pre-Nougat, and from what I see, back then it was all done in native code, it wasn't exposed to Java. Java code would only call `AssetManager.setConfiguration` and later `AssetManager.loadResourceValue` which are both `native` methods.

Answer (score 15):

It's complicated because even if you have a folder named `values-de` it doesn't mean you have any resources there. If you have `string.xml` in `values-de` it doesn't mean you have string value there.

values:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">LocTest</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

values-de:

```
<resources>
    <string name="hello_world">Hallo Welt!</string>
</resources>
```

You can test if a resource for a specific locale is different than the default:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
Resources r = getResources();
Configuration c = r.getConfiguration();
String[] loc = r.getAssets().getLocales();
for (int i = 0; i < loc.length; i++) {
    Log.d("LOCALE", i + ": " + loc[i]);

    c.locale = new Locale(loc[i]);
    Resources res = new Resources(getAssets(), metrics, c);
    String s1 = res.getString(R.string.hello_world);
    c.locale = new Locale("");
    Resources res2 = new Resources(getAssets(), metrics, c);
    String s2 = res2.getString(R.string.hello_world);

    if(!s1.equals(s2)){
        Log.d("DIFFERENT LOCALE", i + ": "+ s1+" "+s2 +" "+ loc[i]);
    }
}
```

It has one fault - you can check one value whether it has translation.

The dirty code above will print something like:

> LOCALE(5667): 51: en_NZ LOCALE(5667): 52: uk_UA LOCALE(5667): 53:
>   nl_BE LOCALE(5667): 54: de_DE DIFFERENT LOCALE(5667): 54: Hallo Welt!
>   Hello world! de_DE LOCALE(5667): 55: ka_GE LOCALE(5667): 56: sv_SE
>   LOCALE(5667): 57: bg_BG LOCALE(5667): 58: de_CH DIFFERENT
>   LOCALE(5667): 58: Hallo Welt! Hello world! de_CH LOCALE(5667): 59:
>   fr_CH LOCALE(5667): 60: fi_FI

Comment: this should be an answer

Answer (score 10):

Inspired by Mendhak's solution I created something a bit cleaner:

```
    defaultConfig {
        ....

        def locales = ["en", "it", "pl", "fr", "es", "de", "ru"]

        buildConfigField "String[]", "TRANSLATION_ARRAY", "new String[]{\""+locales.join("\",\"")+"\"}"
        resConfigs locales
    }
```

Then in Java use:

```
BuildConfig.TRANSLATION_ARRAY
```

Advatages of this method:

- Smaller apk - resConfigs will cut out resources from libraries which you don't need (some have hundreds)
- Fast - No need to parse resource configurations

Comment: That would be my preferred solution, unfortunately it's no good in a multi-module project.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work in a multi-module project? I guess only if more than one module contains string resources - but if only one of them does, that should be fine, no? (I know your comment is years old) @arekolek

Comment: @KonradMorawski in my case I had multiple app modules that should support different sets of languages and wanted to have access to the list of those languages in a library module (used by the app modules), so that the library would know at runtime what languages are supported by the app - BuildConfig can't be used for that

Comment: Ah, I get it. I guess it could still be done by retrieving the BuildConfig on the app module level, and then "injecting" this knowledge back to the library module upon start-up?

Comment: what do you mean? did you read answer? he asked how to get the list and you answered about creating it manually

Answer (score 9):

For anyone using Gradle, I did it like so below it traverses all `strings.xml`, grabs the directory names and figures out the locales from there.  It adds a `String[]` to  `BuildConfig` which you can access as `BuildConfig.TRANSLATION_ARRAY`

```
task buildTranslationArray << {
    def foundLocales = new StringBuilder()
    foundLocales.append("new String[]{")

    fileTree("src/main/res").visit { FileVisitDetails details ->
        if(details.file.path.endsWith("strings.xml")){
            def languageCode = details.file.parent.tokenize('/').last().replaceAll('values-','').replaceAll('-r','-')
            languageCode = (languageCode == "values") ? "en" : languageCode;
            foundLocales.append("\"").append(languageCode).append("\"").append(",")
        }
    }

    foundLocales.append("}")
    //Don't forget to remove the trailing comma
    def foundLocalesString = foundLocales.toString().replaceAll(',}','}')
    android.defaultConfig.buildConfigField "String[]", "TRANSLATION_ARRAY", foundLocalesString

}
preBuild.dependsOn buildTranslationArray
```

So after the above task occurs (on prebuild) the `BuildConfig.TRANSLATION_ARRAY` has your list of locales.

I'm not a Gradle/Groovy expert so this could definitely be a bit neater.

Reasoning - I ran into too many issues implementing pawelzieba's solution, I had no reliable strings to 'compare' as the translations were crowdsourced. The easiest way then was to actually look at the values-blah folders available.

Comment: Thanks for this little piece of code, why using `replaceAll('-r','')` ?

Comment: @Biscuit aah if I recall correctly, it's to deal with some languages like `zh-rCN`

Comment: Yep I've just checked and Android adds an `-r` when specifying the region

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by the answers above I created a simple method to get all app's languages based on provided translations:

```
public static Set<String> getAppLanguages( Context ctx, int id ) {
  DisplayMetrics dm = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
  Configuration conf = ctx.getResources().getConfiguration();
  Locale originalLocale = conf.locale;
  conf.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
  final String reference = new Resources( ctx.getAssets(), dm, conf ).getString( id );

  Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
  result.add( Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage() );

  for( String loc : ctx.getAssets().getLocales() ){
    if( loc.isEmpty() ) continue;
    Locale l = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH ? new Locale( loc.substring( 0, 2 ) ) : Locale.forLanguageTag( loc );
    conf.locale = l;
    if( !reference.equals( new Resources( ctx.getAssets(), dm, conf ).getString( id ) ) ) result.add( l.getLanguage() );
  }
  conf.locale = originalLocale;
  return result; 
}
```

where as `id` arg should be used a `R.string.some_message` which is provided in all translations and contains clearly distinguishable text, like `"Do you really want to delete the object?"`

Maybe it would help someone...

Answer (score 2):

[`LocaleList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/LocaleList.html) or [`LocaleListCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/os/LocaleListCompat) are one of the ways you could get the languages supported by your application.

LocaleList was introduced in API 24.

The thing to consider when using LocaleListCompat is that for API < 24 only the first language tag will be used.

Comment: You are answering a very old post. Please indicate which version of Android your solution targets if it's different from already post answers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The reason I added my answer here is that I couldn't find the solution myself on any other posts and hopefully it will save someone some time searching.

Comment: This method will return supported language list in system setting, not from application

Answer (score 1):

these res-lang actually depends on Locales, so you need to get locale from device and you can get which language is getting shown from locale..

```
Locale myPhoneLocale = Locale.getDefault();
```

You can then call getDisplayLanguage() to know which language is getting shown.

Reference : [Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html)

Comment: same as user370305, i want to know all available languages in my app

Comment: "You can then call getDisplayLanguage() to know which language is getting shown." - if your app supports only English, but device is set to French, you get `français` this way, even though the app is showing English texts

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this?

```
String language = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```

Comment: no, this method just return the default language, I want to know all the languages specified in my res folder

Answer (score 0):

Inspired with the code by@Injecteer
 I have done the following:

for the list of languages ​​that the app supports , it is necessary to pass the default language , since it is not possible to detect

```
public static Map<String,String> getAppLanguages(Context context, String appDefaultLang) {
    Map<String, String> listAppLocales = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    listAppLocales.put("default","Auto");

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            Resources res = context.getResources();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    String[] listLocates = res.getAssets().getLocales();

    for (String locate : listLocates) {

        conf.locale = new Locale(locate);
        Resources res1 = new Resources(context.getAssets(), metrics, conf);
        String s1 = res1.getString(R.string.title_itinerary);
        String value = ucfirst(conf.locale.getDisplayName());

        conf.locale = new Locale("");
        Resources res2 = new Resources(context.getAssets(), metrics, conf);
        String s2 = res2.getString(R.string.title_itinerary);

        if (!s1.equals(s2)) {
            listAppLocales.put(locate, value);
        } else if (locate.equals(appDefaultLang)) {
            listAppLocales.put(locate, value);
        }
    }
    return listAppLocales;
}
```

The result is a list `map<key,value>`of languages ​​supported by the application, the first thing is for if you want to use to populate a listPreference

Answer (score 0):

Another way to read resources during a build with regard of flavors:

```
android {
    // ...

    applicationVariants.configureEach { variant ->

        def generateLocalesTask = task("generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Locales") {
            doFirst {
                def locales = []
                def resDirs = variant.sourceSets.collect { it.res.srcDirs }.flatten()
                resDirs.each { dir ->
                    def valuesDirs = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                        @Override
                        boolean accept(File dir2, String name) {
                            return name.startsWith("values-")
                        }
                    })
                    if (valuesDirs != null) {
                        valuesDirs.each { valuesDir ->
                            def stringsFile = new File(valuesDir, "strings.xml")
                            if (stringsFile.exists()) {
                                def locale = valuesDir.name.replaceFirst("values-", "").replaceFirst("-r", "-")
                                locales.add(locale)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                def localesString = locales.unique().collect{"\"${it}\""}.join(', ')
                def buildConfigClassContent = """\
                    package ${variant.applicationId};
                  
                    public class LocaleConfig {
                        public static final String[] LOCALES = {${localesString}};
                    }
                    """.stripIndent()
                def buildConfigFilePath = "${project.buildDir}/generated/source/buildConfig/${variant.dirName}/${variant.applicationId.replace('.', '/')}/LocaleConfig.java"
                def buildConfigFile = new File(buildConfigFilePath)
                buildConfigFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
                buildConfigFile.text = buildConfigClassContent
            }
        }
        variant.javaCompileProvider.configure {
            dependsOn(generateLocalesTask)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
// Locale.US is optional, in case you want to identify `values/strings.xml` somehow
var locales = new HashSet<>(List.of(Locale.US));

for (var asset : LocaleConfig.LOCALES)
    if (SDK_INT >= LOLLIPOP) {
        locales.add(Locale.forLanguageTag(asset));
    } else {
        var parts = asset.split("-");
        locales.add(parts.length >= 2 ? new Locale(parts[0], parts[1]) : new Locale(parts[0]));
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean:

```
String[] locales = getAssets().getLocales();
```

This would let you get the language that your device have.

Comment: I don't want to have the languages that my device have but the language that my application have