# Listing resource variants

Tags: java, android, xml, resources

I have a few variants of `values/` folder in my Android app (e.g. `values-pl/`, `values-en/`, `values-de/`, etc.). My question is: how to list these variants without hardcoding them? In example above I want to get `en`, `pl` and `de`.

I tried with `AssetManager.getLocales()`, but it lists way too many languages (all languages supported by Android?), I want to list languages only supported by my app. I also tried `AssetManager.list()`, but it doesn't work (it lists content of `assets/` folder, not `res/`).

Thanks.

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611065/get-the-applications-resources-languages maybe?

Comment: There is an answer to the first part of my question, but not the second :)