# How to get list of provided strings translation?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, localization, android-resources

**Background**

I have created two translations - `values-en` and `values-fr` - for my app. I want to let user change app language in UI. So I created and filled a spinner with available locales of system, using `Locale.getAvailableLocales();` method:

```
Spinner languageSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerLanguage);
Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
String[] langs = new String[locales.length];
for (int i = 0 ; i < locales.length ; i++ ){
    // display a more readable language name like "English (USA)"
    langs[i] = locales[i].getDisplayName();
}
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,langs);
languageSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Above code will give me all of available locales in current device. Since this is a long list and might be confusing for my users, I want to display Locales that I have provided with translation.

EDIT: A similar question is [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30375274/how-to-get-programmatically-list-of-supported-languages-in-an-android-project-n?rq=1), comments suggest that there is no direct way.

Although I can provide hard-coded data to my spinner, it would be a better approach to make whole process dynamic.

**Question**

Is there a way to get available translations in run-time?

An ideal method example would be: `getTranslationList();`which eventually return an array of available translated languages in resources, something like: `{"en","fr"}` or `{"values", "values-en", "values-fr"}`.

Comment: did you manage to find a solution? I've been looking for the same thing and didn't find any easy way to do it.

Comment: @TomerPetel No and I won't find. As I stated in the question, it seems there is no direct way. I just left the question open in case someone in the future finds a way.

Comment: thx for updating

Comment: Yea this would be nice...probably just going to hardcode languages for now...