# How do I programmatically validate if a given locale, say wx_rYZ, is supported by my app or not?

Tags: android, localization, android-resources

My android app has below **`values`** directories:

[image]

Now, if I set my device language *(via Settings)* to **wx_rYZ** then I would like to know if my app supports this locale or not.

At the same time I would like to keep the default values folder as is with all the translations.

Answer (score 0):

Get the current locale

```
String current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.toString();
```

You will have to maintain a hashSet of locales that your application support. You can than check if the current locale is present in the hashSet to know if it is supported or not.

Comment: I thought about this but the drawback of this approach is whenever someone adds another locale to app, this hashSet must also be updated. This is something which is not ideal and hence dropped the idea to go ahead with this.

Comment: @Gagan In my opinion this is the cleanest way to achieve this. If you want to dynamically get the list of locales that your app supports take a look at these answers.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611065/get-the-applications-resources-languages and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589521/get-only-the-list-of-locales-that-are-shipped-with-my-android-applicaiton

Comment: I had seen that link before posting the question as the answers present there didn't provide solution for this.. Thanks anyway!