# Difference between Locale.getAvailableLocale and assetManager.getLocale in android?

Tags: java, android, locale

Is there any difference or are they same (except the format they return) ?

Answer (score 1):

After a quick Google, I've found this:
http://androiddevevelopmentnotes.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-find-available-locales-in-andoid.html

> `Locale.getAvailableLocales()` - returns a pretty large number of
>   Locales.
>
> `Activity.getAssets().getLocales()` - returns the Locales that the
>   AssetManager contains data for, which is typically a lot less than
>   what Locale.getAvailableLocales() returns.

Answer (score 1):

From the doc:

> [`getAvailableLocales`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getAvailableLocales())
>
> Returns an array of **all installed locales**. The returned array represents the union of locales supported by the Java runtime environment and by installed `LocaleServiceProvider` implementations. It must contain at least a Locale instance equal to `Locale.US`.

and

> [`getLocales`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#getLocales())
>
> Get the locales that this asset manager **contains data for**.

So the first is returning all locales available on the system and the second one is returning locales "backed by assets"

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611065/get-the-applications-resources-languages/11751526#11751526