# How to get a list of locals for a resource string

Tags: android, locale

There are many [exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android#comment31834862_7989085) when dealing with locals, therefore I thought it would be nice to use the system `Locale.getAvailableLocales()` to list all the locals available for the device.

But I do not provide translations for all the locals, therefore I want to find a method that will give me only the locals for which a specific string resource is available(Ex: `R.strings.welcome`).

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

I think loop-and-find string resource is one of the answer.

```
List<Pair<Locale, String>> stringLocals = getAvailableLocales(R.string.example);
```

method is:

```
private List<Pair<Locale, String>> getAvailableLocales(@StringRes int example) {
    List<Pair<Locale, String>> results = new ArrayList<>();
    Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();

    for (Locale locale : locales) {
        if (isLocaleStringAvailable(example, locale)) {
            String string = getLocaleString(example, locale);
            results.add(new Pair<Locale, String>(locale, string));
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

But it seems that it is not so fast, because there is so many locales to loop (over 600). Therefore, use this settings to prevent too many loops.

```
defaultConfig {

    def locales = ["en", "it", "pl", "fr", "es", "de", "ru"]

    buildConfigField "String[]", "TRANSLATION_ARRAY", "new String[]{\""+locales.join("\",\"")+"\"}"
    resConfigs locales
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45884682/850347

---

You can use this code for get strings by locale:

```
List<String> strings = getAvailableStrings(Locale.KOREA);
```

And methods are:

```
private List<String> getAvailableStrings(Locale locale) {
    List<Integer> stringIds = getAllStringIds();
    List<String> strings = getAllStrings();

    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < stringIds.size(); i++) {
        boolean result = isLocaleStringAvailable(stringIds.get(i), locale);
        if (result == true) {
            results.add(strings.get(i));
        }
    }

    return results;
}

private List<Integer> getAllStringIds() {
    Field[] fields = R.string.class.getFields();
    List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        try {
            int resno = fields[i].getInt(null);
            ids.add(resno);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // Catch exception
        }
    }
    return ids;
}

private List<String> getAllStrings() {
    Field[] fields = R.string.class.getFields();
    List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        String res = fields[i].getName();
        ids.add(res);
    }
    return ids;
}

private boolean isLocaleStringAvailable(@StringRes int id, Locale locale) {
    String globalString = getLocaleString(id, Locale.ENGLISH); // Modify if your default language is not english.
    String localeString = getLocaleString(id, locale);
    return !globalString.equalsIgnoreCase(localeString);
}

public String getLocaleString(@StringRes int id, Locale locale) {
    Configuration conf = getResources().getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = locale;
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    Resources resources = new Resources(getAssets(), metrics, conf);
    return resources.getString(id);
}
```

Comment: No dude, I want the opposite, I want to get all the locales for a specific R.string id