# Android - Defining the default locale

Tags: android, localization, android-resources

I am developing a bilingual android application, which supports german and italian.
At the moment i have a `values-it` with italian strings and a `values` with the german strings.
This works well, unless you are using german and italian on your device.
In this case, the application is always in italian, following this calculation:

```
User Setting: de_DE, it_IT
App Resources: default(en), it

Try de_DE -> fail
Try de -> fail
Try it_IT -> fail
Try it -> Success
```

This is probably because the default is implicitly treated as `values-en`, while in my case it is actually `values-de`.

Is there a way to tell android, that my applications default locale is `de` instead of `en`?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there are any other options or not, one way is to do it programmatically. According to [Ricardo's great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42269965/764809), I've created the following class to change the default Local:

```
public class LocaleHelper {

public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
    String lang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
    if(lang.equals("it") || lang.equals("de"))
        return context;
    String locale = "de";
    return setLocale(context, locale);
}

private static Context setLocale(Context context, String localeSpec) {
    Locale locale;
    if (localeSpec.equals("system")) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            locale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
        } else {
            locale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale;
        }
    } else {
        locale = new Locale(localeSpec);
    }
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return updateResources(context, locale);
    } else {
        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, locale);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private static Context updateResources(Context context, Locale locale) {
    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.setLocale(locale);
    configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, Locale locale) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = locale;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
    }

    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

    return context;
}
}
```

You should use that on your Activity class:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base));
}
```

If you are using `uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy` to change fonts, you should do as follows:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base)));
}
```

---

### Update

Using this outstanding [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11674720/764809) I managed to find the provided languages automatically. So you no further have to hard code `it`, `de` or other provided translations whenever you add a new one to the resources.

```
public class LocaleHelper {

public static Context onAttach(Activity context) {
    Set<String> providedLangs = getProvidedLanguages(context);
    String lang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
    if(providedLangs.contains(lang))
        return context;
    String locale = "de";
    return setLocale(context, locale);
}

private static Set<String> getProvidedLanguages(Activity activity){
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    Resources r = activity.getResources();
    Configuration c = r.getConfiguration();
    String[] loc = r.getAssets().getLocales();
    Set<String> providedLangs = new HashSet<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < loc.length; i++) {
        Timber.e("LOCALE: " +  i + ": " + loc[i]);

        c.locale = new Locale(loc[i]);
        Resources res = new Resources(activity.getAssets(), metrics, c);
        String s1 = res.getString(R.string.app_name);
        c.locale = new Locale("");
        Resources res2 = new Resources(activity.getAssets(), metrics, c);
        String s2 = res2.getString(R.string.app_name);

        if(!s1.equals(s2)){
            if(!providedLangs.contains(loc[i]))
                providedLangs.add(loc[i]);
        }
    }

    return providedLangs;
}

private static Context setLocale(Context context, String localeSpec) {
    Locale locale;
    if (localeSpec.equals("system")) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            locale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
        } else {
            locale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale;
        }
    } else {
        locale = new Locale(localeSpec);
    }
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return updateResources(context, locale);
    } else {
        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, locale);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private static Context updateResources(Context context, Locale locale) {
    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.setLocale(locale);
    configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, Locale locale) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = locale;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
    }

    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

    return context;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm going to try it as soon as possible.

Comment: I just tryed it, but it seems like it now only uses the language I set. What I want instead is, that it uses italian, if italian is the preffered language and german otherwise.

Comment: @Springrbua I just updated `onAttach` method. Please try it again

Comment: @Springrbua I think it is worth to have look at the updated post ;)

Comment: thanks for your effort. I'll probably stick with the current situation, as it usually isn't a big problem and the provided solution looks more like a work-around. I just thought the Android Frameworks provides a straightforward solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

20210715
this seems to work for me. Focus on the statement that identifies the locale and recognize that context must be provided

```
///this function was called from a FRAGMENT and works fine .
////  dateLong = TimeConvert.tcConvertDateToLong(..........,requireContext()
fun tcConvertDateToLong(
        yyyy: Int, MM: Int, dd: Int, HH: Int, mm: Int,context: Context
): Long {
    val mTag64="TimeConvert_tcConvertDateToLong"
    val date:String
    date=yyyy.toString() + "." + MM.toString() + "."+ dd.toString() +" "+ HH.toString() + ":" + mm.toString()
    ////////////-------------------------------------------------------------
    val locale = getLocales(context.getResources().getConfiguration()).get(0)
    //////////-------------------------------------------------------------
    val df = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm",locale)
    return try {
        df.parse(date)!!.time
    }  catch (  e: ParseException){
        java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()
    }
}
```